# How to display docstrings into a repository's Wiki?

Tags: python, github, documentation, wiki, docstring

I have a python project that contains docstrings for every function, method and class. How can I automatically display it in a user friendly way into the repository's wiki, or some other dedicated place in the repository? (I don't know what place is typically used for such things)

Note: the question is about python docstrings, but if there is some general way to do it for all doc types (e.g XML docs in C#, Javadoc in Java, etc..) in GitHub it would be better

Comment: You could write a script to take every docstring from a .py file (or documentation from any language for that matter), then format it and output it all into a documentation.txt file.

Comment: @AAAlex123 there is no way to display the docstring otherwise? (like in python docs? https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_bool) By the way, I am using PyCharm. Maybe it has such functionality that I can use and then transfer to GitHub somehow?

Comment: There most certainly is, but in case there wasn't, or you wanted a more customisable solution, I suggested the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html) to pipe your docstring to a `.md` file and upload that to your Github repo wiki:

Example for the `sys` library:

**Windows CMD**

```
python -m pydoc sys > sys.md
```

**Linux/WSL/OS X**

```
pydoc sys > sys.md
```

Comment: How can I use it for a python package?

Comment: @avivgood2 This can be used for any python module/file. For example you have a `example.py`, then you can just do `pydoc example > example.md`.

Comment: shouldn't I sfecify full path?

Comment: You should use `cd` to get into the same directory as your modules first.

Comment: ok. one last question. Should I use python console / cmd / shell prompt for that? (using Windows 10)

Comment: Oh you are using windows, let me edit my answer. Please let me know if it works.